# Is there a way to use sftp command history if we don't rely on third party tools?

Tags: macos, sftp

I have OS X Mavericks and Sierra on 2 Macbooks, and on both, `sftp` will not do command history. It will show something like

```
^[[A
```

instead. If not using any third party tools or apps, is there a way to make command history work for `sftp` on a Mac?

Comment: At build time, the history for the `sftp` client is provided by `libedit` library. Your OpenSSH was most probably built without that support. You can build it `--with-libedit` if that is an option for you (and description of "without third party tools").

Comment: so it is like, if Apple can build it better on their new OS X update, or ... as part of the command line tools of Xcode... but probably just build it better as part of OS X... (ruby, python, ftp, and sftp are all bundled with OS X, so it may be just good to build sftp better)